# Two separate CSV files and Two tables that share a common column of a primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

so I'm working on a datawarehouse project and I was given 3 csv  files by my professor. The two I'm having trouble with are a mastersales file and a customer lookup. Both of these files share a column that is a CUST_ID I need to be able to insert or  join the master sales file data with the customer dimension file based on the CUST_ID as a primary key. This is my first ever SQL project so I have literally no experience. My question would it be best to join the tables together based on the ID or to insert the master file data as well into the CUST_DIM and delete the columns that don't pertain to a customer? Thank you in advance

Comment: Where do you need the data in the end?

Comment: So I will have a customer_dim, product_dim, and store_dim. I need to disperse the data between those tables. I hope that answers

Comment: Sorry, I meant in the end do you need the data in the database or do you need to export it somewhere else? If you need it all in the database you might as well look at loading in the csv, or at least the important columns. Then you have all the sql tools to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Best idea would be to use a `JOIN` for the CUST_ID with a method like:

```
SELECT CUST_DIM.CUST_BIRTH_DT, CUST_DIM.CUST_CITY_NM, CUST_DIM.CUST_STREET_ADD, CUST_DIM.CUST_POSTAL_CD, CUST_DIM.CUST_STATE_CD, CUST_DIM.CUST_NM, CUST_DIM.CUST_NO, CUST_DIM.CUST_PHONE_NO 
FROM CUST_DIM 
JOIN sales_filev1
ON CUST_DIM.CUST_NO=sales_filev1.**SALES ID NUMBER GOES HERE**
```

This would allow you to like both tables together and manipulate how you see fit.

Comment: Okay so I tried this and I got column was ambiguous

Comment: try tableName.column_name, SecondTable.secondColumn_name

Comment: Same thing:/ does it matter what table I run the SQL in?

Comment: No it doesn't matter if they both use the same ID. Post the code you are trying and ill edit my code to match what you are trying.

Comment: SELECT `CUST_BIRTH_DT`, `CUST_CITY_NM`, `CUST_STREET_ADD`, `CUST_POSTAL_CD`, `CUST_STATE_CD`, `CUST_NM`, `CUST_NO`, `CUST_PHONE_NO`
FROM sales_filev1
JOIN CUST_DIM
ON sales_filev1.CUST_NO=CUST_DIM.CUST_NO;

Comment: Inside my customer_dim table i have these columns CUST_NO,CUST_ID,CUST_INCOME_AM,CUST_CD

Comment: Sorry mate was at lunch              SELECT CUST_DIM.CUST_BIRTH_DT, CUST_DIM.CUST_CITY_NM, CUST_DIM.CUST_STREET_ADD, CUST_DIM.CUST_POSTAL_CD, CUST_DIM.CUST_STATE_CD, CUST_DIM.CUST_NM, CUST_DIM.CUST_NO, CUST_DIM.CUST_PHONE_NO 
FROM CUST_DIM 
JOIN sales_filev1
ON CUST_DIM.CUST_NO=sales_filev1.SALES ID NUMBER GOES HERE

Comment: Okay so that works, but it doesn't actually populate the cust_dim table with the data where the row matches

Comment: Check the 'on' method that the 'CUST_DIM.CUST_NO = sales_filev1.no'  that they do infact match because if they are not showing that means they dont match in the database, you may need to do some debugging.

Comment: Very useful website for learning & testing SQL functions 

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp